# Using C# I want to send text to another form's textbox

Tags: c#, forms

I'm fairly new to C# so please go easy on me.

I have `form1` as the main form and another form called "debug". The debug form has two text boxes, `dbgBox1` and `dbgBox2`. What I am trying to do is, when `debug.Visible == true`,  update the text boxes from form1. I don't want this to happen only on button clicks, etc. 
For example, it's easy to update a textbox that is on form1 (via textbox1.Text = "";) How can I do something similar but update the textbox in the debug form?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296225/reading-from-that-stream-and-sending-text-to-another-forms-textbox) seems close but does not explain itself enough for me to understand.

Comment: there are thousands of questions about this in StackOverflow.Please use google first.

Comment: Also duplicate of  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722461/how-to-pass-textbox-data-between-two-forms) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667629/how-do-i-pass-a-string-value-from-a-textbox-between-forms) and more..

Comment: @Selman22: I Know there are thousands of questions **similar** to this but I have found none that do what I ask.

Comment: What are you asking is `"transfering data between forms"`,that's the **keyword**.And all answers are explain the way of doing this.Once you learn the way you can easily implement it for your current situation.But if you ask for just code then probably you will ask another duplicate versions of this question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good practice to implement a method to change the form state externally, so your forms will be less coupled. Accessing the properties of another form directly generally is not a good idea, including the main form.

```
public partial class debug : Form
{
    public debug()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setdbgBox1Text(string text)
    {
        dbgBox1.Text = text;
    }

}
```

Then you can use:

```
    debug deb = new debug();
    deb.Show();
    deb.setdbgBox1Text("aaa");
```

Comment: The above doesn't quite answer my question. I don't want to send the text on a button click. For example, I want to create the new form, make it visible and then pass it text from Form1 continuously (until I close the debug form).

Comment: But you can use deb.setdbgBox1Text("aaa") anywhere so you can continuously update the debug form from Form1. Just make "debug deb = new debug();" a Form1 member. Every time you call this method the debug window will be updated.

Comment: Ah yes. I misunderstood! Your example does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're instantiating the 2nd form yourself from a form, you can just update it via reference like this:

```
formDebug fd = new formDebug();
fd.Show(this);

fd.dbgBox1.Text = "Box 1 Text";
fd.dbgBox2.Text = "Box 2 Text";

fd.Update();
```